# Is there a simple way to check if each of many non-contiguous cells I want to paste to is empty before copying?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste, with-statement

I have code which pastes data from one spreadsheet to another. It works great. However, the spreadsheet I'm pulling the data from either has actual data, or shows 'NR' in the cell.
At the moment, I have set it up so that any pasted 'NR' data will be removed, but I need to change this so that it either 1. doesn't bother copying 'NR' at all, or 2. doesn't copy over actual data that is already in the cell being pasted to.
This code runs every day, and there will be data only on 1 day per month, which needs to remain in the pasted spreadsheet. I don't want it being overwritten by the 'NR'.

Here is an example of what I have now, but this overwrites legitimate data with 'NR', then removes the 'NR' leaving the cell blank.
Note: the cells I am pasting to are non-contiguous, and this is only a small sample.

I was thinking I need something like a 'with wsElog2 if cell is empty then do the copy otherwise don't, and go to next range' but I don't know how to do this for the semi random cells I have.

```
wsElog2.Range("E61") = wseDNA2.Range("DO15") 'Filtered Effluent Magnesium
wsElog2.Range("E64") = wseDNA2.Range("EA15") 'Filtered Effluent Potassium
wsElog2.Range("E62") = wseDNA2.Range("EE15") 'Filtered Effluent Sodium


'Lagoons 1
wsElog2.Range("G55") = wseDNA2.Range("EU15") 'Ammonia
wsElog2.Range("G48") = wseDNA2.Range("EW15") 'Blue Green Algae
wsElog2.Range("G52") = wseDNA2.Range("EY15") 'E. coli
wsElog2.Range("G59") = wseDNA2.Range("FA15") 'EC
wsElog2.Range("G54") = wseDNA2.Range("FC15") 'Nitrate
wsElog2.Range("G53") = wseDNA2.Range("FE15") 'Nitrite
wsElog2.Range("G57") = wseDNA2.Range("FG15") 'TN
wsElog2.Range("G58") = wseDNA2.Range("FI15") 'pH
wsElog2.Range("G56") = wseDNA2.Range("FK15") 'TP

For Each c In wsElog2.Range("B1:L159")
    If c.Text = "NR" Then
        c.Value = ""
    End If
Next
```

This was solved with the answer provided, with a couple of small alterations to the code as below:
(Note: I didn't get the DEBUG.PRINT sections working, but just got rid of them instead)

```
    
    ' Monitor the behavior in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G), or not.
    Const DEBUG_PRINT As Boolean = True
    
    ' Write the cell addresses to arrays.
    Dim SourceCells() As Variant: SourceCells = Array("DO15", "EA15", "EE15")
    Dim TargetCells() As Variant: TargetCells = Array("E61", "E64", "E62")
    
    ' Existing code that e.g. sets the worksheets, ...
    
    Dim sVal As Variant, n As Long, IsSourceValid As Boolean
    
    For n = LBound(SourceCells) To UBound(SourceCells)
        With wsElog2.Range(TargetCells(n, 1))
            ' Check target.
            If Len(CStr(.Value)) = 0 Then ' blank
                ' Check source.
                sVal = wseDNA2.Range(SourceCells(n, 1)).Value ' store in variable
                If Not IsError(sVal) Then ' not an error value
                    If Len(sVal) > 0 Then ' not blank
                        If StrComp(sVal, "NR", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' not equal
                            IsSourceValid = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If IsSourceValid = True Then
                ' Write.
                .Value = sVal
                ' Reset.
                IsSourceValid = False
                If DEBUG_PRINT = True Then Debug.Print "Copying """ & CStr(sVal) _
                    & """ from """ & wseDNA2.Name & "!" & SourceCells(n) _
                    & """ to """ & .Worksheet.Name & "!" & .Address(0, 0) & """!"
            Else
                If DEBUG_PRINT = true Then Debug.Print "Not copying """ & CStr(sVal) _
                    & """ from """ & wseDNA2.Name & "!" & SourceCells(n) _
                    & """ to """ & .Worksheet.Name & "!" & .Address(0, 0) & """!"
            End If
        End With
    Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Cell Values

```vb
Sub CopyCellValues()
    
    ' Monitor the behavior in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G), or not.
    Const DEBUG_PRINT As Boolean = True
    
    ' Write the cell addresses to arrays.
    Dim SourceCells() As Variant: SourceCells = Array("DO15", "EA15", "EE15")
    Dim TargetCells() As Variant: TargetCells = Array("E61", "E64", "E62")
    
    ' Existing code that e.g. sets the worksheets, ...
    
    Dim sVal As Variant, n As Long, IsSourceValid As Boolean
    
    For n = LBound(SourceCells) To UBound(SourceCells)
        With wsElog2.Range(TargetCells(n))
            ' Check target.
            If Len(CStr(.Value)) = 0 Then ' blank
                ' Check source.
                sVal = wseDNA2.Range(SourceCells(n)).Value ' store in variable
                If Not IsError(sVal) Then ' not an error value
                    If Len(sVal) > 0 Then ' not blank
                        If StrComp(sVal, "NR", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' not equal
                            IsSourceValid = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            If IsSourceValid Then
                ' Write.
                .Value = sVal
                ' Reset.
                IsSourceValid = False
                If DEBUG_PRINT Then Debug.Print "Copying """ & CStr(sVal) _
                    & """ from """ & wseDNA2.Name & "!" & SourceCells(n) _
                    & """ to """ & .Worksheet.Name & "!" & .Address(0, 0) & """!"
            Else
                If DEBUG_PRINT Then Debug.Print "Not copying """ & CStr(sVal) _
                    & """ from """ & wseDNA2.Name & "!" & SourceCells(n) _
                    & """ to """ & .Worksheet.Name & "!" & .Address(0, 0) & """!"
            End If
        End With
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: So to make sure I'm reading this right, this will only copy if the source cell does not have 'NR' in it?

Comment: I just realised I have a lot of my rows determined using a variable, RowNum.  Would I just have the TargetCells array only include the column and alter the code as follows?
```With wsElog2.Range(TargetCells(n) & RowNum)```

Comment: Thanks again VBasic2008 this was very useful. I have answered both my questions by testing it, and the answer to both of them is yes.